# UINavigationController not working (pushViewController ignores the view)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

there are a lot of questions regarding `UINavigationController`. I modify my code to follow Apple examples, but the `pushViewController` method is not working:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

[window addSubview:navController.view];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

LoginController *login = (LoginController*)[self.navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

if([login already_validated] == TRUE) {
    self.timeline = [[TimelineViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Timeline" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [navController pushViewController:timeline animated:YES];

    [self.timeline release];
}

return YES;
```

the view is loaded correctly in the line:

```
self.timeline = [[TimelineViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Timeline" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

...but

```
[navController pushViewController:timeline animated:YES];
```

does not present the view. I've checked and `navController` is not null.

Any ideas?

Best!

Lucas.

---

FIXED!!

The problem resides on the `MainWindow.xib`.

Do NOT set the `rootViewController` on the window class!

If you set the attribute on the XIB file, this view will be on top of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You should never send a `release` to a property directly! Memory management is done in the setter method for you!

instead of:

```
[self.someProperty release];
```

write:

```
self.someProperty = nil;
```

Normally you do this in the `dealloc` method.

In your case simply remove the line `[self.timeline release];` or don't use a property at all.

**EDIT**:

add an autorelease:

```
self.timeline = [[[TimelineViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Timeline" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
```

Comment: Is confusing as it's written right now, but if it is a retain property, actually he has to release the object inside `self.timeline`, because he is allocating it in a line before.

Comment: Thank you gonzalo. Actually I removed the property :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


[window addSubview:navController.view];


[window makeKeyAndVisible];


LoginController *login = (LoginController*)[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];//here remove self


if([login already_validated] == TRUE) {

    self.timeline = [[TimelineViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Timeline" bundle:nil];//remove the nsbundle mainbundle


    [navController pushViewController:self.timeline animated:YES];//here u have to use with self.timeline

    [self.timeline release];

}

return YES;
```

Comment: I've tried to remove and add the things you mention. No luck :(.

Comment: check TimelineViewController nib or Timeline nib u have.and remove nsbundle mainbundle to nil